# How to set Zookeeper IP address in ConsumerGroup instead of Kafka-Host IP address?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have to set zookeeper IP address in ConsumerGroup instead of Kafka-Host IP address. Because I have set replication factor as 3 and 3 brokers were created. So, if one host fails then the another one can take over.

When I tried to put zookeeper IP address instead of Kafka-Host IP address in ConsumerGroup, it doesn't receive any messages which were sent from Producer API.

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node')
var ConsumerGroup = kafka.ConsumerGroup

function createConsumerGroup () {
  var options = {
    kafkaHost: '127.0.0.1:9092',
    batch: undefined,
    ssl: true,
    groupId: 'demoExample',
    protocol: ['roundrobin'],
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fromOffset: 'latest',
    commitOffsetsOnFirstJoin: true,
    outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest',
    onRebalance: (isAlreadyMember, callback) => { callback(); }
  }

  var consumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(Object.assign({ id: 'demo-' + process.pid }, options), 'example')

  consumerGroup.on('message', function (message) {
    message.value = JSON.parse(message.value)
    console.log('Message Received')
  })
}
```

I want that, if I pass zookeeper IP address in ConsumerGroup rather then Kafka-Host IP address, it should receive messages which were sent from Producer API on "example" topic. And if one broker fails then it should receive messages from another broker. As replication factor is set to 3 and 3 brokers were created.

Comment: you don't need to "connect to zookeeper from consumer" in order to achieve replication, kafka will do that for you, no worries. None of the clients talk now with zookeeper, both consumer and producer connect directly to the broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was with the consumerGroup options object.

We have to pass zookeeper IP address in "host" key in options object instead of "kafkaHost" key. This solves the problem and receives all data sent by Producer API. And even automatically switch over to another replica set if one replica set fails.

```
var options = {
    kafkaHost: '127.0.0.1:9092',
    batch: undefined,
    ssl: true,
    groupId: 'demoExample',
    protocol: ['roundrobin'],
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fromOffset: 'latest',
    commitOffsetsOnFirstJoin: true,
    outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest',
    onRebalance: (isAlreadyMember, callback) => { callback(); }
  }
```

The following block of code fix it.

```
var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1:2181', // change in key & value
    batch: undefined,
    ssl: true,
    groupId: 'demoExample',
    protocol: ['roundrobin'],
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fromOffset: 'latest',
    commitOffsetsOnFirstJoin: true,
    outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest',
    onRebalance: (isAlreadyMember, callback) => { callback(); }
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The new consumer API introduced in Kafka `0.9`, does not require a connection with Zookeeper. Group balancing is now handled by Kafka itself. Therefore, you have to provide Kafka Host(s) instead of Zookeeper Host(s).

The [blog post from Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-0-9-is-released/) should shed some more light:

> At the time of the 0.8.2 release of Apache Kafka, which released the
>   redesigned producer client, we had promised to redesign the consumer
>   client as well. And we kept our promise: the 0.9 release introduces
>   beta support for the newly redesigned consumer client. At a high
>   level, the primary difference in the new consumer is that it removes
>   the distinction between the “high-level” ZooKeeper-based consumer and
>   the “low-level” SimpleConsumer APIs, and instead offers a unified
>   consumer API.
>
> This new consumer is implemented using a powerful new server-side
>   facility that makes group management a first-class part of Kafka’s
>   protocols. This has several advantages. First it allows for a much
>   more scalable group facility, which allows the consumer clients to be
>   much simpler and thinner and allows for larger groups with far faster
>   rebalancing. This facility is available to all clients; work is
>   already nearing completion to use it in the C client, librdkafka. This
>   same facility turns out to be broadly useful for managing distributed
>   producing and consuming of data in Kafka; it is the basis for Kafka
>   Connect as well as several upcoming projects. Finally this completes a
>   series of projects done in the last few years to fully decouple Kafka
>   clients from Zookeeper, thus entirely removing the consumer client’s
>   dependency on ZooKeeper. Zookeeper is still used by Kafka, but it is
>   an implementation detail of the broker–clients that use this new
>   facility have no need to connect to Zookeeper at all. This has a
>   number of operational benefits since clients are now always working
>   through the security and quota mechanisms the broker provides. This
>   significantly simplifies the consumer and opens the door for
>   first-class non-Java implementations of the consumer API to emerge
>   over time.